# cannot retrieve the id of dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a dynamic div, along with the table...I want that when i click the image inside the div, it will give the the id of the div on which i have clicked...below is the code. Please any one point out where the mistake is...!?  In the alert box i am unable to get the id of the div

following code creates the div

```
function create_newGrid() {
    //create div for corresponding table
    var tableDiv = $('<div/>').attr({ "id": "settingsDiv-tab" + nooftables });
    var divImage = $('<img/>').attr({ "src": "settingsImage/settings.png", "onclick": "openTableSettings(this);" })
    $(tableDiv).append(divImage);
    // append grid to designer
    $(document.getElementById("center")).append(tableDiv);
    $(document.getElementById("center")).append(table);
}
```

following is the function that executes when a image in the div is clicked

```
function openTableSettings(div) {
    alert($(div).attr("id"));

}
```

Comment: o yes I got it....I have to get the parent element of the image to get the id of the image\

Comment: No problem, easiest way to test code like this is just dump it in the console of chrome or ff or something.

Comment: Gave you an example of how you can test it on this page using the console :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a reference to the img to `openTableSettings()`.  Use `.closest()` to get the div:

```
function openTableSettings(img) { 
    alert($(img).closest("div").attr("id")); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have the onclick on the image, which doesn't have an ID. If you run this in your browser console, it will add a div with text to the bottom of this page and you can see the id being retrieved properly. (your code but adapted)

```
//create div for corresponding table
var tableDiv = $('<div/>').attr({ "id": "settingsDiv-tab", "onclick": "alert($(this).attr('id'));"});
var divImage = $('<p>this is a big bunch of text</p>');
tableDiv.append(divImage);
$(document.body).append(tableDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better if you do

```
var divImage = $('<img/>').attr({ "src": "settingsImage/settings.png", class: "clickable"});
```

and then

```
$(window).on('click', 'img.clickable', function(){
   alert(this.id);
});
```

(this assumes jQuery >= 1.7)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("div > img").click(function() { 
    id = $(this).parent("div").attr("id");
    alert(id);    
})
```